# Setup VPN client on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to follow this tutorial to connect to my home network: https://www.outcoldman.com/en/archive/2014/10/21/ubuntu-as-a-home-server-part-2-openvpn/

I need only the "... to get access to home network" part from it, so I don't want to connect to internet via VPN, I want just connect to my home network with it. The problem that there is no description about how to configure a Windows 8.1 VPN client to do so. I tried out some tutorials about Windows 8.1 VPN, but I suspect that all of them are about connecting to the internet via VPN. Another problem that I could not use the previously generate key, because it required username + password authentication. Is there a way to use the built in VPN tool in Windows to connect to my home network, or should I install a different VPN client?

Comment: A specific problem description would be really helpful. This way, we can't even know whether you opened your router's firewall. Also, did you search on the web regarding OpenVPN setups for the WIndows 8 VPN client, or not?

Comment: @ClassStacker I did almost everything about the VPN server from the tutorial. I don't have firewall on the server computer, it is an Ubuntu 14.04. This part is missing as well: `"To do that you will need to update Routing Tables on your devices, the easiest way to do that will be to add them to your home router (if it supports that). "`. I have a working dyndns (tried out with a HTTP server), but I cannot ping the vpn server, I got "unknown host" message. I set  up a port forwarding on the router. On win 8.1 there was no option to use the auth key generated by the vpn server. :S

Comment: How can you expect to ping the VPN server? But the error message should in fact be be different. Which `ping` command line are you using and from where?

Comment: @ClassStacker `ping x.ddns.net:443` from git bash on windows or from the server itself. None of them worked.

Comment: I suggest you do some basic reading about `ping`. BTTW, are you sure you need an Ubuntu server for the VPN? Why don't you let your router handle it?

Comment: @ClassStacker Because it does not support VPN?

Answer (score 0):

I found here how to configure the Windows client for OpenVPN: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide#ClientConfigFiles

In the program files there is an openvpn folder, which contains server and client configuration samples. These use the .ovpn extension instead of the .conf extension. You need to override a few things, like

```
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\mike-laptop.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\mike-laptop.key"
remote example.ddns.net 443
```

otherwise it is just the same as configuring with .conf files.